# Bootstrap 3 - Carousel - Right and left arrows and gradient don't align with image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the basic Bootstrap 3 carousel in play.

I am trying to figure out the proper way to bring the right and left arrows and gradient so that they overlay the actual image when the image is not full width of the page.

[image: Example]

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-keyboard="true" data-pause="hover" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
              </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
                <img src="~/Content/SlideShowImages/myimage.Name" class="img-responsive center-block" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Caption</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left luluColor"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right luluColor"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got something working, but I think it higlights a problem with trying to do this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6gb6m535/3/)**

**jQuery:**

```
var width = $('div.item.active > img').width();

$('#myCarousel').width(width);

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    var width = $('div.item.active > img').width();
    $('#myCarousel').width(width);
});
```

I've only included the jQuery here because the HTML is the same as what you have posted, except I've used placehold.it images for test images. I'll post the HTML if anyone feels grumpy about it.

Anyway, the jQuery gets the width of the first image and sets the width of the carousel to match, then as the images slide, when the slide action starts it gets the width of the next active image and sets the width of the carousel to match. The height of the carousel will automatically match the height of the image unless you specify a staitc height.

You can also use `slid.bs.carousel` instead of the slide option to make it happen after the image has already slid into place. That makes it a tiny bit smoother, and should guarantee the height/width of the carousel place the arrows and gradient on the sides exactly where they need to be.

However, this highlights a problem with this method: **as the carousel resizes, the user now has to move their mouse to shuffle to the next image manually if that's how they're going through them.** You'll also cause your page to do a lot of reshuffling of page items, depending on how you set everything up.

Granted, you can do what you want, and I don't know the exact reason you need this feature, but it's something to be aware of. There may be other ways to mitigate that problem, but my solution is merely here to show it's entirely possible to dynamically set the width of a Bootstrap carousel based on the currently active image.